# Delete dataverse table row from canvas app

Tags: canvas, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I have a canvas app where I can add and edit table, I also want to be able to delete them, how can I do that?

I've tried this on trash button but it didn't work.

```
Remove(Contacts,Gallery2.Selected)
```

[image]

Comment: `Remove( [@Contacts], ThisItem )` try this and let me know if this works

Comment: I think it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula should be correct. Are you sure 'Contacts' is the datasource of your gallery?

Did you select the row you wanted to delete from the gallery first?

Gallery2.Selected is referencing the selected row. If you add the trash button to your gallery (so it repeats every row), the row will be automatically selected when you press the trash button.

Comment: You are right I had mistake in datasource name, thank you it works. now I just want whole row to be selected when click, because I have text inputs and the user may think he is deleting only selected input.